# Average Value by Grouping

Tags: sql

Trying to get the mean of the `Value` for each different grouping of `TypeID`. Something like

```
SELECT AVG(Value) FROM dbo.TableTest
GROUP BY DISTINCT TypeID
```

TableTest

```
TypeID      PopularityID        CriteriaID      ExposureID     Value
10          20                  5               12             2 
10          20                  4               4              0.90
14          20                  2               10             1.21
15          32                  5               8              0.90
18          20                  3               7              51
```

Comment: `SELECT TypeID, AVG(Value) FROM dbo.TableTest
GROUP BY TypeID `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want:

```
SELECT TypeID, AVG(Value)
FROM dbo.TableTest
GROUP BY TypeID ;
```

Your use of `GROUP BY DISTINCT` suggests that you need to learn or need a refresher on SQL syntax and the syntax of `SELECT` queries.